# How to choose a stable PML for pseudo-spectral method with strongly varying velocity

Tags: finite-difference, reference-request

My friend was working on this, and he asked me about the stability of [PML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfectly_matched_layer) while applying on pseudo-spectral method, I believe his concern was how to choose the difference(if the difference should be chosen with a directional preference, forward/backward, or inflow/outflow) such that the numerical solution is stable over time. I am nowhere an expert on this topic and do not even know how to choose the keywords to google, so here I am requesting some references. Thanks a lot.

Comment: By PML, do you mean "Perfectly Matched Layer"?

Comment: @Paul Yes I am, thanks for pointing this out.